# Cabal install hoogle not working

Tags: linux, haskell, cabal, eclipse-fp, hoogle

I need to configure eclipsefp and install hoogle and scion-browser for setting up a haskell project using mysql.
I tried to install hoogle and scion-browser from Eclipse -> Preference -> Helper executable, and also from the terminal, however unsuccessfully.

```
cabal install hoogle
```

and

```
cabal install scion-browser
```

fail, throwing the following:

> cabal:codec.compression.zlib: premature end of compressed stream.

Edit:
It may be a problem with the cabal version?
If I run cabal --version in terminal, it says:
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library

If I perform cabal update nothing happens.

However, in Eclipse -> Helper Executables there are two versions available:
version 0.14.0
version 1.18.0.2
They are located at different locations, I checked the second one to be used.

Comment: Are you under some kind of proxy ?

Comment: No, there is no proxy

Comment: Does "nothing happen" on `cabal update` or just nothing observable?  I.e. is your package database actually updated (check the time stamp)?

Answer (score 1):

in my case, the downloaded package is broken, figured it out by running `cabal install -v package-name`, removed it manually and finally worked